# Obtain sub array from jagged array

Tags: c#, .net, jagged-arrays

The input to my routine is a jagged array (unfortunately, I have to live with it). It represents a data table (rows and cells).

Now I have to output another jagged array being a sub array of the given input, i.e. I want to have the rows 500-1000.

Is there a nice way to do that? Maybe even something like a *view* on top of the existing data?

I have implemented the worst case scenario so far: creating a second jagged array and copy the sub array to it.

Hope there is a better way you can tell me of :-)

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: @Rahul: can't think of why this would be of any use for answering my question whether there is a "nice" way to do it. I already described my current solution in a way, so that everybody can imagine how to current solution looks like.

Comment: You should not ask for a "nice" answer. "nice" is primarily opinion based

Comment: PS. Microsoft has published some standard code for doing linear algebra with a jagged matrix [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863137.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then may be this?

```
var subArray = yourArray.Skip(500).Take(500).ToArray();
```

Comment: This only gets the rows. Each row would need another set of LINQ to extract specific columns.

Comment: @ja72 But the OP wants to have a new jagged array containing the rows 500-1000 - so this is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

For example you can try this approach, using `yield` keyword.

```
    public IEnumerable<T[]> GetRowRange<T>(T[][] jaggedArray, int rowStart, int rowEnd)
    {
        for(var idx = rowStart; idx <= rowEnd; idx ++)
        {
            yield return GetRowValues(jaggedArray, idx).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetRowValues<T>(T[][] jaggedArray, int row)
    {
        for (var col = 0; col < jaggedArray.Length; col++)
        {
            yield return jaggedArray[row][col];
        }
    }
```

and this is usage:

```
var rowRange = GetRowRange(jaggedArray, 2, 3);
foreach(var row in rowRange)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: `T[,]` is not a jagged array. A jagged array is `T[][]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean using LINQ

```
public double[][] GetSubMatrix(int row, int col, int row_count, int col_count)
{
    return elements.Skip(row).Take(row_count).Select(
        (each_row) => each_row.Skip(col).Take(col_count).ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

My preference for matrix structures is to use jagged arrays without LINQ. You cannot set values on an array easily using LINQ and the commands do get quite long and silly after a while.

I do use `Array.Copy` as much as possible instead of inner loops.

Try this `Matrix` generic class sample:

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    readonly int rows, cols;
    readonly T[][] elements;

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.rows=rows;
        this.cols=cols;
        this.elements=new T[rows][];
        for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            elements[i]=new T[cols];
        }
    }
    public int Rows { get { return rows; } }
    public int Columns { get { return cols; } }
    public T this[int row, int col]
    {
        get { return elements[row][col]; }
        set { elements[row][col]=value; }
    }
    public T[] GetRow(int row) { return elements[row]; } // This is fast
    public T[] GetColumn(int col) // This is slow
    {
        T[] column = new T[rows];
        for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            column[i]=elements[i][col];
        }
        return column;
    }

    public T[][] GetSubMatrix(int row, int col, int row_count, int col_count)
    {
        T[][] result = new T[row_count][];
        for(int i = 0; i<row_count; i++)
        {
            // This is fast
            Array.Copy(elements[row+i], col, result[i], 0, col_count);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void SetSubMatrix(int row, int col, T[][] matrix)
    {
        int row_count = matrix.Length;
        int col_count = row_count>0 ? matrix[0].Length : 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<row_count; i++)
        {
            // This is fast
            Array.Copy(matrix[i], 0, elements[row+i], col, col_count);
        }
    }
}
```